# Mobile Web App not coming up in Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am a newbie to Android.  I have written several small programs with just basic functionality in Android.  I am using the Eclipse plugin for Android.  I am now working with JQuery Mobile and creating a Mobile Web Application.  I have tried researching my answer.  What I have done is: 1. grant user privileges for the Internet for my application.  2.  Test the emulator with the provided web browser so see that one can get out over the internet within the emulator.  I can hit Google with no problem.  When I click on my "News" application, the error comes back that the emulator does not find my html page.

```
/* When a page is loaded in the browser, we get the stored news 
 * categories and process them on after another to create a  list
 * for each news category 
*/

$(document).ready(function () {        
                     showProgress();
                     var storedNewsTxt = $.DSt.get(COOKIE_NAME); 

                     if(storedNewsTxt != null && storedNewsTxt.length > 0){
                        storedNewsArr = storedNewsTxt.split(COMMA);
                     }else{
                        storedNewsArr = new Array();
                     }      
                     numNewsToRestore = storedNewsArr.length;     
                     restore();
                  });
```

Can someone please offer any suggestions on how one debugs this behavior?  Is there a link someone can throw me explaining how to debug mobile web applications?  Suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for reading my post.

Russ

Comment: How are you loading the page? Where is the html file?

Comment: The index.html is located under the asset/www/  directory.  I am clicking on the "News" program within the window inside the emulator.  That is when I get the error saying it can not find the page.

Answer (score 0):

For the good of the group....  Lesson learned.  When you use tutorials, check the source code as it may not match the documented version.   Once I did this, I realized the URL was not formed correctly---duh!